# Unable to copy one react project template

Tags: create-react-app

I got my new laptop and wanna to start the react coding.

First I tried to create a react template directory.

```
npm install create-react-app

create-react-app template
```

Now the npm start on template path working properly.

Then I copy this path to a new one.

```
cp -r template 0429
```

This time npm start not working. Here are the error.

```
  renderzdeMacBook-Pro:0429 renderz$ npm start

 template@0.1.0 start /Users/renderz/myproject/0429
 react-scripts start

module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../scripts/start'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.resolve (internal/module.js:27:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/renderz/myproject/0429/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts:24:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:423:7)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! template@0.1.0 start: react-scripts start
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the template@0.1.0 start script 'react-scripts start'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the template package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     react-scripts start
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs template
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls template
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/renderz/.npm/_logs/2017-04-29T10_00_45_104Z-debug.log
```

First I thought it would be the missing package of 'react-scripts' and I install the 'react-scripts' on global. But not resolve.

Addition:

```
renderzdeMacBook-Pro:0429 renderz$ npm -v
4.5.0
renderzdeMacBook-Pro:0429 renderz$ node -v
v7.9.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Running the `start.js` script manually works if you copy the project with  `cp -r`:

```
node node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js
```

Because `cp -r` just copies the file contents,  doesn't necessarily preserve symlinks.

`npm start` uses the react-scripts bin file, which is at `./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts` however, this should be symlinked into `./node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js`. This symlink means that npm can find the cross-spawn module which is a subdependency of react-scripts.

`cp -a` will preserve symlinks, so avoids the problem.

See more details from [this issue](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/200).

Hope this helps.